# SQL Select Statement based on iOS version

Tags: sql, sqlite, ios13, ios12

The following statement works in my app with the iPhone having iOS 13, However when I test it was iOS12 it crashes and says there is a syntax error around "(".
Any reason for this and possible fix.

I am assuming its got to do with the version of SQLite shipped with iOS12

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY foodname COLLATE nocase ASC) AS RN 
        FROM   foodtable) t1 
WHERE  rn % 5 = 0
```

Comment: Probably the version of SQLite in iOS12 does not support window functions.

Comment: The Select statement selects every 5th record out of the table

Comment: forpas. Would you happen to have a fix? or direct me to where I can research

Comment: Is Foodname unique in the table?

Comment: Yes it is. fields are FoodName, Abbreviation, Source, Description. All Text Fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQLite versions that do not support window functions you can get the same results like this:

```
select f.*
from FoodTable f
where (select count(*) from FoodTable where FoodName <= f.FoodName) % 5 = 0
```